# Get Any/All Active JFrames in Java Application?

Tags: java, swing, list, methods, jframe

Is there a way from within a Java application to list all of the currently open/active (I'm not sure the terminology here) `JFrames` that are visible on screen? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This has the unmistakable odor of bad design.  There should generally be only one frame in an app., and if further top-level components are created that are worth worrying about, keep a reference to them.

Comment: You're probably right, but I don't have tremendous experience in programming and I was just trying to test out an alternate idea. Thank you for your comment and answer though.

Comment: I'll expand on that comment a little.  Generally an app. would have 1 frame.  Anything else that cannot be included into the frame using any number of clever techniques for cramming multiple components into one GUI (e.g. `CardLayout`, `JSplitPane`, `JTabbedPane`, `JDesktopPane`/`JInternalFrame`..) could be shown in a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane`.  The 2nd is modal by default, while the 1st can be specified as modal.  This then means that user input to the parent `JFrame` is blocked while the dialog is open.  For things like gaining further input, modality is very handy.

Comment: No that does not have any odor of anything bad. It is a valid design choice. Actually, we start relying on it in JavaX now.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[`Frame.getFrames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getFrames--) returns an array of all frames.

Alternately as mentioned by @mKorbel, `Window.getWindows()` will return all windows - since `Frame` (& `JFrame`) extend `Window` that will provide all frames, and then some.  It will be necessary to iterate them to discover which ones are currently visible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Stefan Reich's comment.

A very useful method is `Window.getOwnedWindows()`... and one context where it is useful, if not essential, is TDD (Test-Driven Development): in an (integration) test, where you have various `Window` objects on display (`JDialog`, etc.), if something goes wrong before the test has finished normally (or even if it finishes normally), you will often want to dispose of subordinate windows in the tests' clean-up code.  Something like this (in JUnit):

```
@After
public void executedAfterEach() throws Exception {
    // dispose of dependent Windows...
    EventQueue.invokeAndWait( new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if( app.mainFrame != null ){
                for( Window window : app.mainFrame.getOwnedWindows() ){
                    if( window.isVisible() ){
                        System.out.println( String.format( "# disposing of %s", window.getClass() ));
                        window.dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Frame.getFrames()` will do your work.

[From oracle Doc:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getFrames--)

> Returns an array of all Frames created by this application. If called
>   from an applet, the array includes only the Frames accessible by that
>   applet.

A simple example:

```
//all frames to a array
Frame[] allFrames = Frame.getFrames();

//Iterate through the allFrames array
for(Frame fr : allFrames){
    //uncomment the below line to see frames names and properties/atr.
    //System.out.println(fr);        

    //to get specific frame name
    String specificFrameName = fr.getClass().getName();

    //if found frame that I want I can close or any you want
    //GUIS.CheckForCustomer is my specific frame name that I want to close.
    if(specificFrameName.equals("GUIS.CheckForCustomer")){
        //close the frame
        fr.dispose();
    }
}
```

Also you can use [`Window.getWindows()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getWindows--) as others mentioned.