# Embed an executable .jar inside a jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, embed

I have a .jar of a game that I would like to embed inside a `JFrame` of my own program. So when I run my program, it will also launch that .jar and it will be wrapped in my `JFrame`. I'm not sure if this is even possible, haven't found a way yet, so any guidance is great :)

I can't offer much more context because even after an hour or so of googling I'm still completely lost on where to start, if you need any other information feel free to ask and I'll get it asap.

Comment: While it might be possible to embed the game in a JFrame, it's not going to be as simple of "embedding a JAR" like you might embed an applet in a webpage. In this case I think you would need to add the game to the JFrame -- essentially intertwining the two -- and this assumes that's even possible with the game in question. That being said, I think you need to provide more information, like what game it is that you're trying to embed.

Comment: You could simply link the .jar to your project, this way you could create what ever classes the .jar has available.  This would assume that the program was developed properly and the main view is based on component and not a window

Comment: @Pandacoder *"..it's not going to be as simple of "embedding a JAR" like you might embed an applet in a webpage."*  (chuckle) When was the last time *you* tried to embed an applet (*any* applet) into a web page?  I can only guess it was not within the last year or so..  but +1 for *"..provide more information, like what game it is that you're trying to embed."*  OP - link to the place you got the Jar file.  I could download it and, likely within minutes, tell you how practical it will be to embed in your own frame.

Comment: @AndrewThompson You're right, it's been nearly 4 years since I've last used an applet. :P I honestly couldn't think of anything else that was a similar parallel that remained within the confines of Java.

Comment: @Pandacoder  Applets always had their 'quirks' that complicated development and deployment, but became very much more difficult when Oracle decided that every applet needs to be signed by a digital certificate issued by a recognized Certification Authority.  Oh, ..and Chrome is set to remove support for applets altogether, while most other browsers put (yet another) prompt between the user and seeing an applet on screen.

Answer (score 1):

A .jar file is not a swing widget; it's Java archive and can contain class files. What you want to do is add the jar to the classpath, and then load a JWidget class from there.

Comment: Ok, I have the .jar added the the classpath. Could you give me some info about the JWidget class or link me to somewhere I can learn about it? For some reason googling it is giving me some weird results

Comment: Wherever you've learned to deal with JFrames. I have absolutely no idea what's in that jar file; how should I?! you need to understand what you're trying to do before asking for help.

Comment: *"Could you give me some info about the JWidget class.."*  BTW - you seem to have mistaken the ExampleName for an actual, existing class.  A 'widget' is a generic term for an ..object under discussion.  By putting the J in front of it, Marcus meant a Swing based component (AWT components had no letter before them - to distinguish the Swing variants, Sun stuck the J in front).  So a `JWidget` is just a way of saying 'a component that is Swing based'.  ( I hope I understood you correctly, Marcus.  ;) )

Comment: Absolutely, @AndrewThompson. Thanks for chipping in!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how to do this by hacking the jar. Create a new project, add it to your class path. Look at the manifest and what class the main method is in.

Then create your own main method which calls MainClass.main(args);
Then do a sneaky Frames.getFrames() as described here [Get Any/All Active JFrames in Java Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364535/get-any-all-active-jframes-in-java-application). Once you have a handle the jframe you can 'steal' the components and add it to your own and presto!