# Get modal dialog instance swing

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, thread-sleep

I have an application if I click on `button1` it will show a modal dialog `dialog1` (But I don't have instance of the `dialog1`.), as well it will initiate a Thread, where in the thread does some processing, and mid of the Thread processing while in `dialog1` the Thread wants to show an alert maybe the server is not connected. But the focus is not above the `dialog1`. It is loading as sibling to `dialog1`. Is there any way to show the alert to child of `dialog1`

Here is the sample.

```
public class Main1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Thread show = null;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;

public Main1() {
    setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton("Button1");
    jButton1.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 30);
    jButton1.setVisible(true);
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            show.start();
            //For Example I'm having this. I have a function call which will create and show a dialog similar to this. 
            java.awt.Frame frame = new java.awt.Frame();
            JDialog dialog1 = new JDialog(frame, true);
            dialog1.setBounds(20, 20, 300, 300);

            dialog1.show();
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jButton1);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    show = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                shoe();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    setDefaultCloseOperation(2);

}

private void shoe() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "HEELO");
}

public static void main(String... f) {
    new Main1().setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Is there anyway to get the child modal instance of the Main1 in any means? So that I can provide that instance to the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "HEELO");` instead the `this` or any other way to achieve this?

Correct me, if my understanding is wrong. Pardon me if this is duplicate.

Comment: read Oracle trails - Event Dispatch Thread and Initial Thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, finally sorted it out. From the help of the question [Get Any/All Active JFrames in Java Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364535/get-any-all-active-jframes-in-java-application)

I got the active window from the list and gave that as parent

```
private void shoe() {
    Component parent = this;
    Window[] allWindows = Window.getWindows();
    for(Window window : allWindows){
        //Validate and find the appropriate window by its instance name or someother mean
        parent  = window;
     }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "HEELO");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your implementation. In my opinion, the main one is that you are modifying state of swing components outside the event-dispatching thread. This is not me, you can read that in Java Concurrency in Practice: "The Swing single-thread rule: Swing components and models should be created, modified, and queried only from the event-dispatching thread."

My first tip would be read more about [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). It seems that's exactly what you want to do.

My second tip is try to improve modularization of your program. By improving modularization of your application, you can achieve what you want.

```
public class Application extends JFrame {

    Thread show = null;

    public Application() {
        setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        getContentPane().add(createActionButton());
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(2);
    }

    private createActionButton() {
        button = new javax.swing.JButton("Action Button");
        button.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 30);
        button.setVisible(true);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                JDialog actionDialog = new ActionDialog();
                new ConnectionWatchdogTask(actionDialog).execute();
                actionDialog.show();
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Application().setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class ActionDialog extends JDialog {

    public ActionDialog() {
        super(new Frame(), true);
        setBounds(20, 20, 300, 300);
    }
}

public class ConnectionWatchdogTask extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {

    private JDialog parentDialog;

    public ConnectionWatchdogTask(JDialog dialog) {
        parentDialog = dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            return findConnectionStateOfServer();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parentDialog, "Warning of some sort");
    }
}
```