# is there any Accessor method in java to get the current JFrame object initialized in a constructor of my class?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
public class MyClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

 public MyClass() {
  super("Frame Window");
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  setSize(700, 500);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  JButton setInv = new JButton("set invisible");
  setInv.setVisible(true);
  setInv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
  add(setInv);

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  MyClass obj = new MyClass();
  obj.setVisible(true);

 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if (e.getActionCommand() == "set invisible") {


   // I want an Accessor method for the parent JFrame and then I want to  
   // set it invisible here!

  }
 }
}
```

---

A person suggested `getParent()` method, but it is not working as I want!
`getParent()` returns some container in this case it is `JFrame` I think..

I have tried `getParent().setInvisible(false);`
but nothing happens..
I know it is error in my logic or something but what should I do?

Java is flexible but full of exceptions at many points!

there is one thing that if I dont extend MyClass from JFrame and create a public instance of `JFrame` and then `setVisible(false);` can be called by its reference!
but i do not want to do so...because i have made a project with a lot of classes and i do not want to change my code like this...
any help guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Any/All Active JFrames in Java Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364535/get-any-all-active-jframes-in-java-application)

Comment: Also have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: no use.. JFrame is not hiding or whatsoever!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can create a reference by  `JFrame farme = this` or if used within the class you can simply use `this`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added an `ActionListener` to your `JButton`. Also, you're not disposing or hiding your `JFrame` in your `ActionListener`.

As a side note: `String` is an `Object`. Use `String::equals` instead of `==`.

```
public class MyClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public MyClass() {
        super("Frame Window");
        setSize(700, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton setInv = new JButton("set invisible");
        setInv.addActionListener(this);
        add(setInv);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        obj.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("set invisible".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
if (e.getActionCommand() == "set invisible") {
        setVisible(false); // or this.setVisible(false);
 }
```