# How to add a parentComponent (JFrame) to a JOptionPane which is initialized in another package/class?

Tags: java, class, components, parent

Normally i am using *this* when the JOptionPane implementation is in the same class, but how do I set a parentComponent from another class?

Comment: Show some code. I would use an argument for the parent...

Comment: Maybe this may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364535/get-any-all-active-jframes-in-java-application